# File handling in c program to read integers

Tags: c, file, file-handling, stdio

This is my code. This does not produce any output and does not even error.  Can anyone please explain why?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *ptr = NULL;
  ptr = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

  int i;
  int numberArray[6];

  for (i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    fprintf(ptr, "%d ", numberArray[i]);
  }

  fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: You opened the file for reading only, so the fprintf calls will fail. Did you mean to *read* numbers from the file instead of writing them? If so then consider using fscanf.

Comment: What do you want to do, read and display the file or write to the file?
fopen with "r" is for reading from the file and fprintf is for writing to the file. So it's not compatible.

Comment: You didn't get an error because you didn't check for any errors.  If you change the `fprintf` call to `if(fprintf(ptr, "%d", numberArray[i] ) < 0) perror("fprintf");` you will probably get output along the lines of `fprintf: Bad file descriptor`, because the file is opened for reading, not writing.